# HTML form field clearing on leave

Tags: html, regex

When I tab out of an HTML form field (5+4 zip code), the field clears if I've typed only 5 digits, but the digits remain if I fill in all 5+4. I'm using the `jquery.maskedinput` plugin for masking. Why don't the 5 digits remain if that's all I type?

Here's a repro in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dEfE8/1

```
<input data-val="true" 
 data-val-length="The field Claimant Zip Code must be a string with a maximum length of 10." data-val-length-max="10" 
 data-val-regex="The field Claimant Zip Code must match the regular expression &#39;^(\d{5}|\d{5}-\d{4})$&#39;." 
 data-val-regex-pattern="^(\d{5}|\d{5}-\d{4})$" 
 data-val-required="The Claimant Zip Code field is required." 
 id="Claimant_Zip" 
 name="Claimant.Zip" 
 title="Claimant Zip Code" 
 type="text" 
 value="" />
```

**UPDATE**: additional pertinent code

This is attached to the field in question. It's part of the jquery.maskedinput plugin:

```
$("#Claimant_Zip").mask("99999-9999");
```

Comment: Show the rest of the code...

Comment: @Sparky I added the only other code which which seems like it might be pertinent. This is one field of a massive form. If you think there's something else that might help, I'm glad to post it.

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out what you're doing.  You originally used the `[jquery-validate]` plugin tag and yet clearly there's no `.validate()` code.  What is `.mask()`?  Show enough code to compile a concise working example... don't make people guess at what this is.

Comment: Oh. I'm calling $("#UrIntakeForm").valid(); when they click the Submit button, so maybe that's not a relevant tag since this problem occurs before they click any buttons.

Comment: It's relevant if you're using that plugin and it has to do with this problem, but there's not enough code for me to tell.

Comment: Construct a jsFiddle demo.

Comment: Good idea. The bug seems to repro there. http://jsfiddle.net/dEfE8/1/

Comment: As I think about this more, I'm wondering if the hyphen that appears after you type the first 5 digits is causing the problem. Maybe the RegEx is making the digits disappear because of the hyphen. I would've hoped that would've been ignored, but maybe not.

Comment: Please add your jsFiddle into your OP to make it less likely to get closed.  Also, start off your question by stating which plugin you are using... it's a critical piece of the puzzle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As per the documentation of the "masked input" plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/):

> By design, this plugin will reject input which doesn't complete the
>   mask. You can bypass this by using a '?' character at the position
>   where you would like to consider input optional.

Adding a `?` just before the hyphen fixes it:

```
$("#Claimant_Zip").mask("99999?-9999");
```

**OP's jsFiddle working: http://jsfiddle.net/dEfE8/2/**